# Desplazar y mostrar textbox en VB6

Tags: vb6

cómo están?

Tengo en Visual Basic 2 checkbox. Al seleccionar alguno de ellos abajo se habilita un textbox para completar con texto, y más abajo tengo otros objetos que para el ejemplo no vienen al caso.

El problema es que ambos textbox ocupan lugar en mi formulario (Por más que estén en disabled).
Es posible que cuando no estén habilitados no ocupen lugar, y cuando estén habilitados de desplacen los objetos de abajo?

Espero que se haya entendido.

Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes ocultarlo y desplazarlo hacía algún lado en donde no ocupe lugar. Es sencillo, sería algo como esto

```
    Dim lugarOriginal = Caja.Location

    AddHandler chkHabilitarCaja.CheckedChanged, Sub()

                                                    If (chkHabilitarCaja.Checked) Then
                                                        Caja.Visible = True
                                                        Caja.Location = lugarOriginal
                                                    Else
                                                        Caja.Visible = False
                                                        Caja.Location = New Point(0, 0)
                                                    End If

                                                End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo mejor que puedes hacer es colcoar el objeto en un **Frame**, podría ser que ese **Checkbox** que estas colcoando requiera tener más interfaces u otros objetos relacionados.
En ese caso puedes colocar Visible o no el frame.
**Para ubicar el cotrol (mover en la pantalla) puedes trabajar con las propiedates `Top` y `Left`**, de esa manera puedes mover todos tus objetos en el formulario.

Mi sugerencia **es que crees diversos `Frame`** le puedes colcoar la propiedas **`Apperaence = 0-Flat`, `BorderStyle = 0 - None`,** colocas dentro los checkbox y otros objetos relacionados y luego mueves el Frame con las propiedades que te indiqué antes.
Espero te sirva mi sugerencia.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer que un `texbox` sea invisible (estando oculto en el formulario). Pero a pesar de la propiedad aplicada se crea un espacio que hace parecer que no esta del todo oculto.

invisible: `TextBox1.visible = False`

> ¿Como puedo evitar el desplazamiento que hace este espaciado en el
>   formulario?